# How to get all the users that editing document in WOPI programmatically?

Tags: c#, ms-wopi

I am working on some improvements on WOPI integration on my app and I have integrated it in my app with some other document locking mechanism. So I need to know is all the users have done editing the same document in the Coauthering scenario and if the users are done editing I need to unlock the document from the App side.
I tried with the "UNLOCK" header and sometimes it does not correctly send the header and the app gets stuck until the lock timeout happens. Is there any other way to track is all the users are done editing the document or who are the users still on the document?